# Por que recebo null no onPostExecute?

Tags: android, asynctask

Este código está voltando apenas null o return, como posso corrigir ele?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MecanismoString extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private Context context;
    private Interface execinterface;

    private String retorno;

    MecanismoString (Context context, Interface execinterface){

        this.context = context;
        this.execinterface = execinterface;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Ion.with(context)
                    .load(params[1])
                    .setBodyParameter("login", params[2])
                    .setBodyParameter("senha", params[3])
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject resultado) {

                                retorno = resultado.get("perfil").getAsString();

                        }
                    });

        return retorno;

    }

    public void onPostExecute(String retorno) {

        execinterface.carregarString(retorno);

    }
}
```

quando seto o debug para ler o código

```
retorno = resultado.get("perfil").getAsString();
```

ele retorna o valor do bd correto, mas  no onPostExecute apenas faz a leitura de null..

Comment: Caro Tiaho, isso me parece Java não https://ion-lang.org, ou entendi algo errado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ion, neste caso, é uma [lib/api](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Comment: @ramaral **pois é**, acho que deu pra entender que o titulo da pergunta soa estranho, já que é uma API não tem sentido escrever *"Ion linguagem"*, concorda? E a falta de tag na pergunta ainda pode confundir mais. Entendo que não tenhamos a tag como no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ion para ter um wiki e uma breve descrição, mas o problema maior mesmo é o começo do titulo ;)

Answer (score 1):

O uso da AsyncTask, neste caso, não faz sentido, o processamento feito pela api [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) já é assíncrono.

O resultado que chega ao `onPostExecute()` é nulo porque a linha `return retorno;`, do método `doInBackground()`, é executada primeiro que o método `onCompleted()`. Lembre que `onCompleted()` é chamado assincronamente pelo Ion.

Quando faz o *debug* funciona porque o processo de *debug* é lento, dando tempo ao Ion fazer o processamento e chamar o método `onCompleted()` antes do return ser executado.

Altere o código de modo a apenas usar o `Ion.with()`.

Comment: Vou testar, vou estudar mais afundo o íon para fazer essa alteração, o asynk nesse caso não é necessário, minha intenção era entender para na outra activity chamar várias conexões separadas...